# Fetching UDT value from cassandra resultset

Tags: spring-boot

I have a table of orders with a set of UDT type of values given below:

```
create table keyspace.ORDERS (
 email text,
 order_id int,
 order_total float,
 shipments set<frozen<keyspace.shipping>>,
 so on
);
```

Here shipping is a UDT created seperately as below:

```
create type shipping(
 name text,
 quantity_shipped int,
 tax float,
 and so on
);
```

How can i fetch the Order details and the UDT value in my java code after excuting this query:
select * from orders where email = 'some email id';

Answer (score 0):

Check those links, ether will help u to start with java - cassandra implementation and basic practices:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial